# how to use template tag in if condition django?

Tags: django, django-templates

my template tag:-

```
@register.filter("participants_count_in_sessions")
def participants_count_in_sessions(session_id):
    class_session_participants_count = ClassJoin.objects.using('p5M').filter(classSession=session_id).count()
    return class_session_participants_count
```

and how i am using it in my templates inside if:-

```
{% for item in data_list %}
<td class="text-center">{% if item.id | participants_count_in_sessions %}<a href="#">{% endif %}{{ item.id | participants_count_in_sessions }}</a></td>
{% endfor%}
```

and error i am getting by using this way:-

`TemplateSyntaxError at /session-on-the-basis-of-class/1/
Could not parse the remainder: '|' from '|'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the spaces between your filter pipe:

```
{% if item.id|participants_count_in_sessions %}
```

The [template language](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/templates/#filters) will only recognise it as a filter if there are no spaces - otherwise it thinks you're passing a variable to the template tag, and then fails to parse it.